# Get project statistics from Gitlab API

Tags: laravel, guzzle, gitlab-api

I'm using Guzzle to access Gitlab's API, i'm trying to get my project statistics but i don't know where i should use the parameter "statistics".

That's what i am doing so far:

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://gitlab.com/']);
$projects = $client->request('GET', 'api/v4/projects/PROJECT-ID',
[
    'headers' => [
        'PRIVATE-TOKEN'     => 'TOKEN',
        'statistics'        => 'true'
        ],
]);
```

API docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project

Thank you.

Comment: Please include a link to the API doc section you are referencing.

Comment: API doc added, sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit**

Try this:

`/projects/PROJECT_ID?statistics=true`

Comment: That's what i've been trying, but i keep getting: {"error":"404 Not Found"}. (I can get the project info without the statistics)

Comment: See my edit, maybe it's needed as a query parameter,

Comment: Oh, that was it!! Thank you.